# How to use a Wireless ADSL modem Router as a Access Point?

Tags: router, wireless-router, lan, modem, bridge

I have two modes similar this:

[image]

I live on the first floor of an apartment. Also one of the mentioned modem is inside my apartment (connected to the ADSL port) and has internet as well. I connect to it using my cellphone (through WiFi) and laptop (through LAN cable) and use the internet; all fine.

Recently I've bought 25 Meter of CAT6e LAN cable to share my internet with a modem located on the second floor of apartment. I did the wiring as well (I've plugged in one end of the LAN cable to port 2 of my modem and the other end to port 2 of my upstairs modem).

Also, I've set `bridge` mode for the upstairs modem. Now, when I get connected to the upstairs modem, sometimes it has internet as well, but sometimes I see a exclamation-mark on the WiFi icon (on my cellphone) and there is no internet.

My first question, why does it work sometimes and not always? And how can I fix the issue?

---

**The exact name of modes if needed:**

- The main one (on my apartment): D-link 2740u
- The upstairs one: Tp-link TD-W8961N_V4

Comment: Did you disable DHCP service on the upstairs modem?

Comment: @user1686 No, [it's enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxCds.jpg). I cannot find any button to make it disable through the modem's interface.

Comment: How about "Interface setup" or similar section that lets you change the DHCP range? Disabling it is something you _will_ need to do.

Comment: @user1686 I see.. Sure, I will try to make it disable .. thanks

Answer (score 1):

In short, when a device is supposed to work as a bridge alongside an existing router, it *must not* have its own DHCP server active as well – otherwise your devices will frequently pick up the wrong "gateway" via DHCP (and possibly wrong other configuration).

Comment: Ok, when I want to make the DHCP server disable, it asks me for "gateway" and "dns" .. what should I write there?

Comment: Are you sure that's not the DHCP _client_ section (WAN port) that you found?